# Efficient way to Identify xlsx & csv files in a directory, which contain specific string in the data

Tags: python, string, file, xlsx

For GDPR purposes, I am trying to identify all spreadsheets within a directory, containing specific strings in the data.

The following code has worked on small files, but takes too long to be practical with any larger spreadsheets (1000+ rows).

It's worth mentioning that I don't know which columns these strings will appear in, so can't use cell location to improve efficiency.

If there's a better way to do the following could you please share?

```
    def list_files(dir):
    r = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for name in files:
       r.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return r


    all_files = list_files("filepath")


    filenames = []

    for f in all_files:
    if not f.endswith((".xls", ".xlsx")): continue
    wb = load_workbook(f)

    for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    for a in range(1, sheet.max_row+1):
    for b in range(sheet.max_column):
    if sheet[a][b].value:
    if str(sheet[a][b].value).upper() in("STRING_1","STRING_2","STRING_3"):
    filenames.append(f)


    set(filenames)
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation for readability?

Answer (score 0):

> If there's a better way to do the following could you please share?

**If you have Linux there is. And if you don't you'll only need a terminal emulator like Cygwin or Baboon in Windows.**

I've created two files: example.xlsx (newer format of xls) and example.csv and added data into each file.

Inside those files I put some strings like: dodo, lolo, string1, string2 among others.

```
mortiz@alberta:~/Documents/test$ ls -ltr
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 mortiz mortiz 4822 Apr 20 16:34 example.xlsx
-rw-r--r-- 1 mortiz mortiz   68 Apr 20 16:34 example.csv
```

There's an utility in almost every linux distro called "grep" which let you search "strings" inside almost anything.

There are two easy ways:

> **Unziping the xlsx files and using grep**

when you unzip the xlsx, you'll find a directory called "lx" inside it an xml file with the data called "sharedStrings.xml"

```
mortiz@alberta:~/Documents/test$ unzip example.xlsx 
Archive:  example.xlsx
  inflating: _rels/.rels             
  inflating: docProps/app.xml        
  inflating: docProps/core.xml       
  inflating: xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels  
  inflating: xl/workbook.xml         
  inflating: xl/styles.xml           
  inflating: xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml  
  **inflating: xl/sharedStrings.xml**    
  inflating: [Content_Types].xml
```

By now we just unzipped the file, we'll see the output of grep below.

> **Converting xlsx to xls and using grep**

The xls format is easier to read, so using this command we will generate a version of the xlsx in xls, then using strings to read its content.

```
   mortiz@alberta:~/Documents/test$ libreoffice --headless --convert-to xls example.xlsx
    convert /home/mortiz/Documents/test/example.xlsx -> /home/mortiz/Documents/test/example.xls using filter : MS Excel 97
```

> **Now using grep to find the files with specific strings**

Finding the strings with this utility would be the easier and fastest way I know.

Because you need to know which files have those strings you must use grep, the -R (recursive) and i (insensitive, doesn't matter about camel case).

```
 mortiz@alberta:~/Documents/test$ grep -Ri lolo *
    example.csv:no data,lolo,foo
    Binary file example.xls matches
    xl/sharedStrings.xml:<sst xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" count="12" uniqueCount="12"><si><t xml:space="preserve">string1</t></si><si><t xml:space="preserve">string</t></si><si><t xml:space="preserve">string2</t></si><si><t xml:space="preserve">no data</t></si><si><t xml:space="preserve">lolo</t></si><si><t xml:space="preserve">foo</t></si><si><t xml:space="preserve">test</t></si><si><t xml:space="preserve">mia</t></si><si><t xml:space="preserve">ami</t></si><si><t xml:space="preserve">nono</t></si><si><t xml:space="preserve">toto</t></si><si><t xml:space="preserve">dodo</t></si></sst>
```

To print only the filenames add the parameter "l", this will print each file with the string "lolo" inside:

```
mortiz@alberta:~/Documents/test$ grep -Ril lolo * 
example.csv
example.xls
xl/sharedStrings.xml
```

Grep will work well with xml, csv, xls or plain text files, that's why we need to unzip or convert the xlsx :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Miguel, I would like to try your solution but am quite new to this kind of scripting, and don't have the tools on my work machine.

I was shown this Python code, which works on my xlsx files. (the field names i'm searching for are usually pasted in the first row of a spreadsheet & this code returns when a match is found).

The process still has room for improvement. Converting the files to csv (or xls?) and parsing as single string would speed things up.

```
import xlrd
import glob



def search_excel(path, phrases):
    try:
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    except xlrd.biffh.XLRDError:
    # Assumed False if document fails to open (e.g. invalid format/corrupt)
        return False
    for sheet in wb.sheets():
        for row in sheet.get_rows():
            for cell in filter(lambda x: x.ctype==1, row):
                # Only operate on string typed cells
                try:
                    if any(phrase in cell.value for phrase in phrases):
                        # Return as soon as possible if criteria fulfilled
                        return path 
                except TypeError:
                    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Recursively searches all nested directories/files for files
    # Change the path here.
    file_paths = glob.glob("...path...", recursive=True)
    search_phrases = ['string_1','STRING_1','string_2','STRING_2']
    list_comp = [search_excel(path, search_phrases) for path in file_paths]
```